# Ionicframework photo editor

Tags: plugins, ionic-framework, editor, photo

I am trying to add a photo editor functionality to my ionic framework application. How ever I couldn't find a decent sdk that goes with it. I'd like add 
aviary/creative
 sdk but there is not an obvious way to do it. I tried `angular-aviary plugin` for cordova but that is not working anymore. Please help me find a good photo editor sdk that works with cordova/ionic framework. Any help would be appreciated, thanks...

Comment: did you found a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

I've spent about a week looking for the same thing. Beyond the Creative SDK there is also the img.ly PhotoEditor SDK which offers Android, IOS, and HTML5 as well. But as with Creative none of it is easily compatible with Ionic. I'm still looking for a solution but would be very interested if others have ideas as well!

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your post, but this doesn't look like an answer to me.  With a little more reputation, you'll be able to post comments.  If you're actually intending to post a new question, the "Ask Question" button in the upper right should help.

Comment: did you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the PhotoEditor SDK [Cordova Plugin Demo](https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-cordova-demo) and the [guide for integrating the editor under Ionic and Cordova](https://blog.photoeditorsdk.com/photoeditor-sdk-cordova-dabe146e6c13) to get an idea of how to get the editor working under Ionic. Basically, it works like this:

> The idea is to create a Cordova app that allows the user to open an image from their photo library and edit this image using the PhotoEditor SDK on iOS and Android. This is done by using an existing library to access native photo pickers on both platforms and passing the path to the found image to a plugin. The plugin manages the configuration and opening of the PhotoEditor SDK’s editor and passes the edited image back to Cordova.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I was in search of this functionality and founded a proper documentation for **ionic Framework** from [PhotoEditor SDK](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/) . Please follow the instructions given here to add Photo Editing functionality in **ionic app** [Quickstart for ionic Framework](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/quickstarts/ionic)
Hope it will help someone.